# Rendering 3D Models With Textures That Have Alpha In OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, alpha-transparency, depth-buffer

So Im trying to figure out the best way to render a 3D model in OpenGL when some of the textures applied to it have alpha channels.

When I have the depth buffer enabled, and start drawing all the triangles in a 3D model, if it draws a triangle that is in front of another triangle in the model, it will simply not render the back triangle when it gets to it. The problem is when the front triangle has alpha transparency, and should be able to be seen through to the triangle behind it, but the triangle behind is still not rendered.

Disabling the depth buffer eliminates that problem, but creates the obvious issue that if the triangle IS opaque, then it will still render triangles behind it on top if rendered after.

For example, I am trying to render a pine tree that is basically some cones stacked on top of each other that have a transparent base. The following picture shows the problem that arises when the depth buffer is enabled:

[image: Depth Buffer Enabled]

You can see how you can still see the outline of the transparent triangles.

The next picture shows what it looks like when the depth buffer is disabled.

[image: Depth Buffer Disabled]

Here you can see how some of the triangles on the back of the tree are being rendered in front of the rest of the tree.

Any ideas how to address this issue, and render the pine tree properly?

P.S. I am using shaders to render everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not using any partial transparency (everything is either 0 or 255), you can <strike>glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)</strike> and that should help you. The problem is that if you render the top cone first, it deposits the whole quad into the z-buffer (even the transparent parts), so the lower branches underneath get z-rejected when its their time to be drawn. Enabling alpha testing doesn't write pixels to the z buffer if they fail the alpha test <strike>(set with glAlphaFunc)</strike>.

If you want to use partial transparency, you'll need to sort the order of rendering objects from back to front, or bottom to top in your case.

You'll need to leave z-buffer enabled as well.

[edit] Whoops I realized that those functions I don't believe work when you're using shaders. In the shader case you want to use the discard function in the fragment shader if the alpha value is close to zero.

```
if(color.a < 0.01) {
   discard;
} else {
   outcolor = color;
}
```

Comment: ... or use a `discard` in your fragment shader if the alpha is below your required threshold in any environment without support for the alpha test (such as ES 2.0 or WebGL).

Comment: They do work when you have shaders (in desktop OpenGL). What doesn't work is alpha test when you're using [core OpenGL 3.1 or above](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts).

Comment: @Tim So I tried using discard, and it appears to remove any color change performed by the fragment shader. However, it does not seem to affect the depth buffer at all. When using discard, I get the same results as shown in the picture where the depth buffer is enabled.

Comment: I also tried glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST) before rendering the tree (which is a single model btw), but that also does not seem to effect the results.

Comment: ACTUALLY, I set the glAlphaFunc() in addition to using GL_ALPHA_TEST by doing the following:  
  
`glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);  
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER,0.9f);  
// Render Tree  
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);`  
  
And that worked! Although, this will not work with semitransparent models. Is there any way to render a semitransparent model without having depth buffer issues?

Comment: @Jeremy Not without presorting the polygons. Its a common problem in rendering, and quite difficult sometimes. Here's a good article about it: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting

Answer (score 0):

You needs to  implement a two-pass algorithm.

The first pass render only the back faces, while the second pass render only the front faces.

In this way you don't need to order the triangles, but some artifacts may occour depending whether your geometry is convex or not.

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong, but this is because when you render in 3d you do no render the backside of triangles using Directx's default settings, when the Z is removed - it draws them in order, with the Z on it doesnt draw the back side of the triangles anymore. 
It is possible to show both sides of the triangle, even with Z enabled, however I'm thinking there might be a reason its normally enabled.. such as speed..

```
Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, Value);
```

value can equal

```
D3DCULL_NONE - Shows both sides of triangle
D3DCULL_CW - Culls Front side of triangle
D3DCULL_CCW - Default state
```